# Can you turn the pages of an ebook on your iPad with your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, remote-control

Can you use your iPhone as a remote control for your iPad, to turn the pages of an ebook? How so?

Answer (score 1):

There is feature described in documentation [Use Switch Control on your device to control another Apple device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205644). Is it capable to deliver desired result?

Comment: Wow, didn't even know this existed.